# XMLHttpRequest getting data from php How to load on html div and level

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

please someone help me to solve this problem.

i am getting data with  XMLHttpRequest from php as json array, here is the data.

[Data I am getting from php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MFHM.jpg)

with this Codes

```
const API_PATH = 'http://localhost/api/';
window.onload = function(){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
document.getElementById("all_service").innerHTML = this.responseText;

};

request.open('GET', API_PATH + 'getServices.php');
request.send(null);
}
```

how to load on div and level

```
<div id="all_service">
    <label class="service-name">Service Name</label>
    <label class="service-description">description</label>
    <label class="service-offers">deals</label>
    <img   class="service_image" src="img/service1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: parse the JSON, get the values from the individual fields, write them into the relevant place in the code using JavaScript's well-documented DOM manipultion functions. There are a billion tutorials you can already consult if you're not familiar with the basics. Since it's a list of services in the JSON though, rather than one, consider using a HTML table, or having a way to duplicate the HTML you've shown in the div, to be able to format multiple results.

Comment: Thank you brother, actually i am very new on JavaScript , it will be very helpful, if you can give me an example  or any reference of this kind of work.

Comment: A simple google search will show you how to parse JSON with Javascript, another one will get you tutorials on how to use JavaScript to generate HTML. No need for new tutorials or examples, or even to paste links - with a search engine, the world is already at your fingertips. Come back if you have a specific question. If your JS knowledge is not up to this task yet, then you wouldn't understand any examples we provided  you anyway, so it would be pointless. Trying yourself is the best way to learn. Ask again if you've tried something, even a small part of it, and got stuck on a specific issue.

Comment: P.S .Just a friendly note - not everyone here is a "brother" or wishes to be thought of as one. Plenty of sisters are programmers too, and probably aliens and insects too, for all I know! I'm not offended personally, but for the future it's better to use neutral language or just refer to people by their usernames, so that you don't get it wrong by accident. Don't make any assumptions :-)